# Delphi desktop screenshot in Windows10, issue with GetDeviceCaps

Tags: delphi, screenshot

How can I get the correct screen size to take a screenshot in Windows10? it seems to get incorrect values (maybe DPI issue?)

i.e

```
// screenshot
b := TBitmap.Create;
DC := GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);
try
  b.Width  := GetDeviceCaps (DC, HORZRES) ;
  b.Height := GetDeviceCaps (DC, VERTRES) ;
  BitBlt(b.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;
finally
  ReleaseDC (GetDesktopWindow, DC) ;
end;
```

on a 4K screen will only capture a small portion on the upper left corner.

Comment: Some information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162729.aspx).

Comment: Yes this is the issue with DPI or more accurately the lack of high DPI support by your application. So Windows is running it in so called scaling mode which affects mani results that Windows API returns especially about the actual screen size. This was added to Windows in order to sort of maintain backward compatibility with older application that are not designed for screens with such high resolution and would result in their UI to be to small and tiny to be usable. Dalija Prasnikar already provided an answer on how to deal with this bellow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make your application fully High DPI aware in order to get proper values for taking screen snapshot.

You can do that by adding following section into your application manifest

```
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
```

---

Complete example of custom manifest for Windows 10

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
            <!-- Windows 10 --> 
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>

            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>

            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>

            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      </application> 
  </compatibility>

  <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="MyApplication"
    version="1.0.0.0" 
    processorArchitecture="*"/>

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>

</assembly>
```

---

Note: Windows 10 have introduced Per-monitor DPI awareness. Above manifest turns that awareness on with `true/PM` value (`PM` - Per Monitor).

Since Delphi introduced support for Per-Monitor DPI in Seattle, applications compiled with older versions will not properly scale in multi-monitor setups that have different DPI settings for each monitor on Windows 10. Depending on the purpose of your application and user base you can either live with such behavior or you would have to upgrade to newest Delphi (it is also important to note that this is new feature and it does have some bugs that may or not be relevant in your case)

Comment: In Delphi 10 Seattle and later, you can set DPI awareness in the Project Options instead of having to manipulate the manifest directly (unless you are using a custom manifest, of course). See [New Option to Enable High-DPI Awareness in Your VCL Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What%27s_New#New_Option_to_Enable_High-DPI_Awareness_in_Your_VCL_Applications).

Comment: Thanks. That sorts the screenshot issue, but it seems to mess with the scaling of the VCL, like.. manually setting form width at runtime results in a smaller (trimmed down) window missing part of the form, and some VCL elements in another form are all displaced in different positions than designed; if I disable scaling that goes away, but then the form is tiny. What do you suggest? (Delphi XE8)

Comment: Dalija's answer raises as many issues as it solves. Your app isn't DPI aware, and for sure an XE8 app is not per monitor dpi aware.  So you need to make it so, or not declare it to be DPI aware. With the latter route you can use a separate process that is dpi aware to take the screen shot.

Comment: When you set form width or other dimension values at runtime you are using pixel values meant for default 100% scale. You will have to apply proper (actual) scale to those values before you set them. You should set your forms Scaled property to true, and fix elements that are not properly positioned. Or like @DavidHeffernan suggests use another process to capture screen.